# dropdown wont hide while using media queries with JS

Tags: javascript, css, events, drop-down-menu, onclick

i used javascript for hiding my dropdown for small screens. it used to work before using a media query like this

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1009px) {
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 55px;
  }
  .show {
    display: block;
  }
  .dropbtn {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: #4CAF50;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .dropdown {
    text-decoration: none;
    position: center;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

And the java script to close the dropdown on clicking on outer window is

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but now when media query was added, this doesn't seem to be working.please give me an answer. i even used jQuery but even that doesn't work out. is it the problem of media query?what should i do?

Comment: Can you provide your html?

Comment: I can't quite understand, you currently have this CSS media query to work up to 1009px screen width, but you are trying to remove a .show CSS class that isn't listed on your CSS. One way to work it would be to ADD a CSS hide Class that has `.hide{display:none !important;}`